# How to create a custom skimage.future.graph.rag which is given as a input to cut_normalized and ncut?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, scikit-image

I am trying to create a custom adjacency graph with RAG but all the examples only have graph creation using `rag = graph.rag_mean_color(img, labels)`

I DON'T want to use this function and want to define the weights with my custom measures. So I wrote the following code

```
labels1 = segmentation.slic(img_i.reshape(img.shape[0],img.shape[1]), compactness=30, n_segments=200)
out1 = color.label2rgb(labels1, img_i.reshape(img.shape[0],img.shape[1]), kind='avg')
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(out1)
print(labels1.shape)
```

[image]

...

```
 g_seg = graph.rag.RAG() 
    for ix in range(0,img.shape[0]):
        for iy in range(0,img.shape[1]):
            idx = ix*img.shape[1] + iy
            g_seg.add_node(idx,labels=[labels_slic[idx]]) 
    win_rad = 7 
    for i in range(0,img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,img.shape[1]):
            for ii in range(-int(win_rad),int(win_rad)):
                for jj in range(-int(win_rad),int(win_rad)):
                    if i+ii>0 and i+ii<img.shape[0] and j+jj>0 and j+jj<img.shape[1]: 
                        idx = i*img.shape[1] + j
                        idc = (i+ii)*img.shape[1] + (j+jj)
                        w_tx = g_tx[idx][idc]['weight']
                        w_ic = g_ic[idx][idc]['weight']
                        g_seg.add_edge(idx, idc, weight=(w_tx*w_ic))
```

But when using this graph for normalized cut I am getting wrong output

```
labels3 = graph.cut_normalized(labels1, g_seg,5.0,10)
```

[image]

So my understanding is that I am destroying the special structure of the image while creating the graph because I took the nodes a 1D array discarding their 2D coordiantes. **So I need help in understanding how can I create a graph the keeps the 2D structure of an image intact and gives results as the ones we get with `rag = graph.rag_mean_color(img, labels)`**

Comment: How are you creating the second image you show? Have you looked at the `show_rag` function? I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, although instead of nested loops I suggest using `scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`. See the implementation of the RAG building functions for details/inspiration!

Comment: PS: Interesting problem! If you figure it out, could you please send a write-up about it to our mailing list at scikit-image@python.org? We might like to add it to our gallery. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own version of a RAG with your own custom weights between adjacent nodes like so:

```
from skimage.future.graph import RAG
import numpy as np

def rag(image, labels):
   #initialize the RAG
   graph = RAG(labels, connectivity=2)

   #lets say we want for each node on the graph a label, a pixel count and a total color 
   for n in graph:
       graph.node[n].update({'labels': [n],'pixel count': 0,
                             'total color': np.array([0, 0, 0],
                             dtype=np.double)})
   #give them values
   for index in np.ndindex(labels.shape):
       current = labels[index]
       graph.node[current]['pixel count'] += 1
       graph.node[current]['total color'] += image[index]

   #calculate your own weights here
   for x, y, d in graph.edges(data=True):
       my_weight = "do whatever"
       d['weight'] = my_weight

   return graph
```

- image: your input image
- labels: labels for each pixel of image

You should also check out the source code of `graph.rag_mean_color`.The above code was based on that.
[rag_mean_color source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/future/graph/rag.py#L295)